# python django: How can I determine if a div should show or hide based on the parameter passed to template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I need to set a div to show or hide based on the parameter that passed in from django views.py, but I just couldn't get it to work. My code is like the following:

In the body:

```
{% if report_type == "detail" %}
    visibility("detail");
{% endif %}
```

In javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function visibility(reportType) {
        console.log(reportType);
        if(reportType == "detail") {
            $('#executive_summary').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

However the above code just doesn't work. Can somebody give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or normal js? Two dont mix like your syntax does.

Comment: Where is the `{% if...` block going? If you don't place it in a script element, and in one that exists *after* the page has finished loading (either by using jQuery's `$(function onLoad(){})` magic or by putting a `<script>visibility('detail')</script>` tag at the very end of your document) it will never go off. That is probably why your console line is never getting reached. Then you will need to fix your use of the jQuery api as everyone has mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

By pure CSS:

```
        {% if report_type != "detail" %}
            <div style="display: none;">
        {% else %}
            <div style="display: block;">
        {% endif %}
        ...
        </div>
```

Or by using JavaScript (jQuery):

```
    {% if report_type != "detail" %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#executive_summary').hide();
    </script>
    {% endif %}
```

By JavaScript functions:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* If wanted to run when page is loaded. */
        $(function() {
            // Handler for .ready() called. 
            visibility("detail");
        });

        function visibility(reportType) {
            if(reportType == "detail") {
                $('#executive_summary').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#executive_summary').hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the nonexistent `style` attribute of the jQuery object returned by your `'#executive_summary'` selector. jQuery objects don't have the same attributes and methods as DOM nodes. Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function visibility(reportType) {
        console.log(reportType);
        if(reportType == "detail") {
            $('#executive_summary').hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will do what you want, but if you absolutely, necessarily, must directly set the display attribute, you could replace that one line with:

```
$('#executive_summary').css('display', 'none');
```

But that is not as clean as just using `.hide()`

Comment: Thx for your response, but right now even the console.log(reportType) won't print anything to firebug console, so I'm wondering the js that I added doesn't work at all. I'm new to web-dev so, got a lot of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the function call in a javascript tag.  Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{% if report_type == "detail" %}
    $('#executive_summary').toggle();
{% endif %}
</script>
```

Comment: OP could definitely shorten his code, but the problem isn't the location of the function call, but rather the use of `$().style`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Good catch, but without a javascript block, the function won't execute.